# Is web scraping allowed?

Tags: web-scraping

I'm working on a project that requires certain statistics from another website, and I've created an HTML scraper that gets this data every 15 minutes, automatically. However, I stopped the bot now, as in their terms of use, they mention they do not allow it.

I really want to respect this, and especially if there's a law prohibiting me from taking this data, but I've been contacting them through email several times without a single answer, so now I've come to the conclusion that I'll simply grab the data, if it is legal.

On certain forums I've read that it IS legal, but I would much rather get a more "precise" answer here on StackOverflow.

And let's say that this is in fact not illegal, would they have any software to spot my bot making several connections every 15 minutes?

Also, when talking about taking their data, we're talking about a single number for each "team", and this number I will transfer in to our own number.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it asking for legality of screen scraping. This depends on many factors that can't be reasonably answered here.

Comment: the answer is "it depends"

Comment: imho, if you honoring settings inside `robots.txt`, then webmaster is nothing to complain about.

Comment: @ankhzet different jurisdictions have different laws.

Comment: Well I'm in Europe, Denmark specifically... When it comes to the internet, isn't it rather hard to place it under certain jurisdictions? The website I need this data from is also from Europe I believe.

Comment: @DanielA.White, imagine a dialog: _Webmaster: "I say, `Crawl-delay: 5 > robots.txt`". Bot: "`Okay... not more than once in 5 minute...`". Webmaster: "No! Bad! Bad robot! Go away!"..._ Is this what you meant? LOL xD

Comment: legal questions are off topic for the so broad nature of them. i would consult a lawyer.

Comment: How `allowed` action can be `illegal`?

Comment: Alright, well, I realize now this is quite an unclear question, and for that I apologize. Thanks anyway though.

Comment: @Mikkel, nothing unclear, just somebody confusing legal/illegal with allowed/disallowed

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about managing a business relationship, communicating between the question OP and a third party, and/or dealing with a legal issue. In other words, it's not about programming as defined in the [help/on-topic]. You might be able to get help from the Customer Service for the company you are interfacing with. If you want an interpretation of legal requirements, it might be appropriate to ask on [law.se].

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I'll quote Pablo Hoffman's (Scrapinghub co-founder) answer to "What is the legality of web scraping?", I found on other site:

> First things first: I am not a lawyer and these comments are solely
>   based on my experience working at [Scrapinghub](http://scrapinghub.com), please seek legal
>   assistance accordingly.
>
> Here are a few things to consider when scraping **public data** from websites (note that the following addresses only US law):
>
> - As long as they don't crawl at a disruptive rate, scrapers do not breach any contract (in the form of terms of use) or commit a crime
>     (as defined in the Computer Fraud and Abuse Act).
> - Website's user agreement [is not enforceable](http://www.nelsonmullins.com/articles/browse-wrap) as a browsewrap agreement because companies do not provide sufficient notice of the
>     terms to site visitors.
> - Scrapers accesses website data as a visitor,
>     and by following paths similar to a search engine. This can be done
>     without registering as a user (and explicitly accepting any terms).
> - In Nguyen v. Barnes & Noble, Inc. the courts [ruled](http://newmedialaw.proskauer.com/2014/09/08/browsewrap-agreement-held-unenforceable-against-consumer-due-to-insufficient-notice/) that simply placing a
>     link to a terms of use at the bottom of webpage is not sufficient to
>     "give rise to constructive notice." In other words, there is nothing
>     on a public page that would imply that merely accessing the
>     information is subject to any contractual terms. Scrapers gives
>     neither explicit nor implicit assent to any agreement, therefore
>     breaches no contract.
> - Social networks, for example, assign the value of becoming a user (based on call-to-action on public page), as the ability to: i) Gain access to full profiles, ii) Identify common friends/connections, iii) Get introduced to others, and iv) Contact members directly. As long as scrapers makes no attempt to perform any of these actions they do not gain "unauthorized access" to their services and thus does not violate [CFAA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_Fraud_and_Abuse_Act)
> - A thorough evaluation of the legal issues involved can be seen here: http://www.bna.com/legal-issues-raised-by-the-use-of-web-crawling-and-scraping-tools-for-analytics-purposes

Comment: This is the closest I think I will get to an answer, so I will mark this one as the answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

There must be `robots.txt` file in root folder of that site.

There are specified paths, that are `forbidden` to harass with scrappers, and those, which is `allowed` (with acceptable timeouts specified).

If that file doesn't exists - anything is allowed, and you take no responsibility for website owners fail to provide that info.

---

Also, [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots_exclusion_standard) you can find some explanation about `robots exclusion standard`.

Comment: Hit and run? Nice ideology...

Comment: Only if they're not wearing a sign that says "please don't hit me".

Comment: Although it's ethical to read robots.txt and crawl only allowed pages, it's not legally enforced