# Possible to get blocked from scraping a site?

Tags: python, selenium, screen-scraping

I am writing a code in python using selenium and Beautiful Soup to scrape Upwork for job listings and descriptions. I now keep getting an error that says:

```
 "Access to this web page is denied.  Please make sure your browser 
 supports JavaScript and cookies and that you are not blocking them 
 from loading. To learn more about how Upwork uses cookies please 
 review our Cookie Policy."
```

Do they not want people to scrape their sites?

Comment: this might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32429445/is-web-scraping-allowed

Answer (score 0):

You may have to do

1. clear the cache and cookies
2. disable all the ad blockers

For more information, check [Upwork](https://community.upwork.com/t5/Freelancers/Access-to-this-web-page-is-denied/td-p/352445/page/2)

Answer (score 0):

Upwork have official API and Python lib as well so they might not be that keen on you scraping the website.

You can find the documentation here.

https://developers.upwork.com/?lang=python#

There is a jobs endpoint that does what you want.

https://developers.upwork.com/?lang=python#jobs