# Unable to get price of the product as output from an Amazon.in product details page

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

The output screen is blank when i try to print the price of a product from amzaon.in (it worked with flipkart btw)

```
url='https://www.amazon.in/Lenovo-K8-Plus-Venom-Storage/dp/B079JC4K7C/ref=sr_1_1?s=electronics&ie=UTF8&qid=1545233164&sr=1-1&keywords=lenovo%2Bk8%2Bplus&th=1'

r=requests.get(url)
soup=BeautifulSoup(r.content,"html.parser")
store=soup.find_all("div",{"class":"a-section a-spacing-small"})
for item in store:
    price = item.find_all("span",{"id":"priceblock_ourprice"})
    print(price.get_text())
```

Expected output: 8098(as of current price)

Actual: blank screen

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its asking how to scrape sites in violation of the terms of service

Comment: what how? they literally allow us to scrape their sites in their robots.txt

Comment: @Jason can you link to relevant tos, I'm merely interested

Comment: @Kingshukrox You're confusing *spidering* (indexing content) with *scraping prices*. Amazon [explicitly tries to stop the latter](https://www.quora.com/Why-cant-Amazon-prices-be-scraped)

Comment: @Machavity i am fairly new to this concept and it is difficult for me to understand it , can u please suggest what should i do/learn to solve this?

Comment: @Kingshukrox Just understand that `robots.txt` is obeyed by content indexing spiders. It's not a license to grab whatever data you want.

Comment: Theres an interesting discussion here on the subject https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32429445/is-web-scraping-allowed which was closed as being too broad. Overall, the consensus of opinion is to get professional legal advice or written permission before scraping a site you do not own.

Comment: @Kingshukrox https://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html/?nodeId=508088 . specifically the license and access section

Comment: @jason i am not doing any sale or commercial profit by using amazon services , i am try to learn how things work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The price listing gets blocked by amazon. If you look at `soup` you can find that the price is not listed but instead it shows the follwoing message:

```
<!-- For automated access to price change or offer listing change events,
                                             please refer to the MWS Subscription API:
                                             https://developer.amazonservices.in/gp/mws/api.html/276-5247872-0590350?ie=UTF8&section=subscriptions&group=subscriptions&version=latest
                                        -->
```

I would advise you to use the official API to fetch prizes. If this is no option for you you will have to automate your browser. This could be achieved with [selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/).

Comment: i tried learning selenium , here is my code(i dont know why it is not running) . Link to my [code](https://github.com/Kingshukrox/py-scraping/blob/master/usingselenium/first.py)

Comment: I can't help you with the code alone. What's the error you're having? I think it's probably about chromedriver but I can't be sure from the code alone. However there are many great tutorials on first steps with selenium. Just make sure you have the right driver and also make sure the driver version matches the version of your browser (that has once cost me 2 days of debugging)

Comment: this is the [error](https://pastebin.com/bVvf5sZc) i am getting while trying to run

Comment: Then I'd suggest checking out https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home for more info just as suggested in the error message or using Firefox with geckodriver instead