# file_get_contents returns 403 forbidden with user agent - PHP

Tags: php, web, screen-scraping, user-agent

I'm just trying to get the title from this product page, however it keeps showing a 403 forbidden error.

> Warning: file_get_contents(https://www.brownsfashion.com/uk/shopping/jem-18k-yellow-gold-octogone-double-paved-ring-17648795): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden in /Applications/AMPPS/www/get_prod.php on line 13"

I tried adding the user-agent in there but still doesn't seem to work. Maybe it isn't possible.

Code below:

```
        <?php
include('simple_html_dom.php');

$context = stream_context_create(
    array(
        "http" => array(
            "header" => "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36"
        )
    )
);

echo file_get_contents("https://www.brownsfashion.com/uk/shopping/jem-18k-yellow-gold-octogone-double-paved-ring-17648795", false, $context);
?>
```

Comment: TOS of that site state `you are not allowed to 'scrape' content`. Maybe the blacklisted your IP

Comment: @user3783243 I reproduced the error, so it doesn't look like an IP blacklist.

Comment: But since the site doesn't allow web scraping, you shouldn't waste time trying to solve this problem.

Comment: I would not use PHP for content scraping: how do you handle content injected/created by javascript ad DOM ready?

Comment: @Barmar you can scrap it with selenium or playwright. I tried it with both and it works.

Comment: @MeT Just because you can doesn't mean you should. It's still a violation of the TOS.

Comment: @Barmar i think it depends, my opinion agrees with the following link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32429445/is-web-scraping-allowed#:~:text=As%20long%20as%20they%20don,Computer%20Fraud%20and%20Abuse%20Act).

Comment: @MeT Just because it's legal doesn't mean you should.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This website has 3 anti bots systems:

1. Riskified.
2. Forter.
3. Cloudflare.

They are used to prevent DoS/DDoS atacks, crawling tasks.... Basically you can't easily crawl them with a simple request.

To bypass them you need to simulate/use real browser. You can use [selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/) or [playwright](https://playwright.dev/python/docs/intro).
I will show you an example of crawling this website with **playwright** and python.

```py
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright

with sync_playwright() as p:
    browser = p.webkit.launch(headless=True)
    baseurl = "https://www.brownsfashion.com/uk/shopping/jem-18k-yellow-gold-octogone-double-paved-ring-17648795"
    page = browser.new_page()
    page.goto(baseurl)
    title = page.wait_for_selector("//a[@data-test='product-brand']")
    name = page.wait_for_selector("//span[@data-test='product-name']")
    price = page.wait_for_selector("//span[@data-test='product-price']")
    print("Title: " + title.text_content())
    print("Name: " + name.text_content())
    print("Price: " + price.text_content())
    browser.close()
```

I hope I have been able to help you.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to actually show an example and look into the issue properly! This is very useful :D